# Spark repartition based on size

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Our Spark application consumes from Kafka and writes to Iceberg tables. Each batch of raw data is processed and split according to the target tables without any shuffle but the size of raw data for each table is not evenly divided. What is the best option to repartition this dataset by size? Both repartition() and coalesce() require an exact partition count. I believe Spark's Adaptive Query Execution applies to queries with shuffles, correct?